# Save data to multiple endpoints from a single save button in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using a tabbed form (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/TabbedForm.html) in react-admin. The data entered in every form should be updated/created in their respective endpoints when the form is saved. Right now I have 5 forms and 5 different endpoints. Is there any way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

React-admin has no built-in component to do that. You'll have to build your own based on `useUpdate` and react-hook-form's `useForm` hooks.